# Bootstrap-Tab control inside Modal disappears after switching tab first time

Tags: twitter-bootstrap

I have a modal control that pops up on click of a link.This modal control has a tab control ,with 3 tabs .When the modal opens up and i click on a tab ,the tab does switch to the clicked one however the tab pane disappears .How to prevent the tab pane from disappearing? I am using Bootstrap v4.2.1

This is a link to my website where the problem is http://www.nakireddi.com/ .
If you click on myworks link the modal pops up with tab pane .Below is the code for the modal with the tab pane.

```
<div id="MyWorks" aria-hidden="true" aria-labelledby="exampleModalLongTitle" class="modal fade" role="dialog"
      tabindex="-1">
      <div class="modal-dialog modal-xl" role="document">
        <div class="modal-content fullscreencontent">
          <div class="modal-header">
            <h5 id="MyWorksTitle" class="modal-title">
              My Works
            </h5>
            <button aria-label="Close" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" type="button">
              <span aria-hidden="true"> × </span>
            </button>
          </div>
          <div class="modal-body backgroundprism">
                   <div id="myTabContent" class="tab-content">
                    <div class="tab-pane fade show active" id="home">
                         <ul class="nav nav-tabs">
                    <li class="nav-item">
                        <a class="nav-link active" data-toggle="tab" role="tab" href="#home">All</a>
                    </li>
                    <li class="nav-item">
                        <a class="nav-link" data-toggle="tab" role="tab" href="#websites">Websites</a>
                    </li>
                    <li class="nav-item">
                        <a class="nav-link" data-toggle="tab" role="tab" href="#themes">Themes</a>
                    </li>

                </ul>
                        <br />       
                                <div class="row">
                                    <div class="col-12 col-sm-12 col-md-4 col-lg-4 col-xl-4">
                                        <div class="card  border-warning  mb-3 animated fadeIn " id="ChibiTaxi" style=" margin-left: 7px; ">
                                            <div class="card-header">Taxi-Bootstrap template</div>
                                            <div class="card-body">
                                                Content 
                                            </div>
                                        </div>
                                    </div>


                             <div class="tab-pane fade" id="websites">

                                <div class="row">
  <iv class="col-12 col-sm-12 col-md-4 col-lg-4 col-xl-4">
                                        <div class="card border-danger mb-3 animated  "  style=" margin-left: 7px; ">


    <div class="card-header">Chemical Factory-Website</div>
                                            <div class="card-body">
                                               Content 
                                            </div>
                                        </div>
                                    </div>


                    <div class="tab-pane fade" id="themes">
                         <div class="row">
                                    <div class="col-12 col-sm-12 col-md-4 col-lg-4 col-xl-4">
                                        <div class="card  border-warning  mb-3 animated fadeIn "  style=" margin-left: 7px; ">
                                            <div class="card-header">Taxi-Bootstrap template</div>
                                            <div class="card-body">
                                               Content

                                            </div>
                                        </div>
                                    </div>
                                 </div>


                       </div>

               </div>
                </div>
          <div class="modal-footer">
            <button class="btn btn-primary" data-dismiss="modal" type="button">
              Close
            </button>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
```

Answer (score 0):

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width">
  <title>JS Bin</title>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-Gn5384xqQ1aoWXA+058RXPxPg6fy4IWvTNh0E263XmFcJlSAwiGgFAW/dAiS6JXm" crossorigin="anonymous">
</head>
<body>
  <nav>
    <div class="nav nav-tabs" id="nav-tab" role="tablist">
      <a class="nav-item nav-link btn btn-danger active" id="nav-home-tab" data-toggle="tab" href="#nav-home" role="tab" aria-controls="nav-home" aria-selected="true">All</a>
      <a class="nav-item nav-link btn btn-danger" id="nav-profile-tab" data-toggle="tab" href="#nav-profile" role="tab" aria-controls="nav-profile" aria-selected="false">Websites</a>
      <a class="nav-item nav-link btn btn-danger" id="nav-contact-tab" data-toggle="tab" href="#nav-contact" role="tab" aria-controls="nav-contact" aria-selected="false">Themes</a>
    </div>
  </nav>
  <div class="tab-content" id="nav-tabContent">
    <div class="tab-pane fade show active" id="nav-home" role="tabpanel" aria-labelledby="nav-home-tab">
      <div class="row">
        <div class="col-md-3 col-12">
          <img width="100%" src="https://media.wired.com/photos/5c1ae77ae91b067f6d57dec0/master/pass/Comparison-City-MAIN-ART.jpg" alt="">
        </div>
        <div class="col-md-3 col-12">
          <img width="100%" src="https://media.wired.com/photos/5c1ae77ae91b067f6d57dec0/master/pass/Comparison-City-MAIN-ART.jpg" alt="">
        </div>
        <div class="col-md-3 col-12">
          <img width="100%" src="https://media.wired.com/photos/5c1ae77ae91b067f6d57dec0/master/pass/Comparison-City-MAIN-ART.jpg" alt="">
        </div>
        <div class="col-md-3 col-12">
          <img width="100%" src="https://media.wired.com/photos/5c1ae77ae91b067f6d57dec0/master/pass/Comparison-City-MAIN-ART.jpg" alt="">
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="tab-pane fade" id="nav-profile" role="tabpanel" aria-labelledby="nav-profile-tab">
      <div class="row">
        <div class="col-md-4 col-12">
          <img width="100%" src="https://media.wired.com/photos/5c1ae77ae91b067f6d57dec0/master/pass/Comparison-City-MAIN-ART.jpg" alt="">
        </div>
        <div class="col-md-4 col-12">
          <img width="100%" src="https://media.wired.com/photos/5c1ae77ae91b067f6d57dec0/master/pass/Comparison-City-MAIN-ART.jpg" alt="">
        </div>
        <div class="col-md-4 col-12">
          <img width="100%" src="https://media.wired.com/photos/5c1ae77ae91b067f6d57dec0/master/pass/Comparison-City-MAIN-ART.jpg" alt="">
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="tab-pane fade" id="nav-contact" role="tabpanel" aria-labelledby="nav-contact-tab">
      <div class="row">
        <div class="col-md-3 col-12">
          <img width="100%" src="https://media.wired.com/photos/5c1ae77ae91b067f6d57dec0/master/pass/Comparison-City-MAIN-ART.jpg" alt="">
        </div>
        <div class="col-md-3 col-12">
          <img width="100%" src="https://media.wired.com/photos/5c1ae77ae91b067f6d57dec0/master/pass/Comparison-City-MAIN-ART.jpg" alt="">
        </div>
        <div class="col-md-3 col-12">
          <img width="100%" src="https://media.wired.com/photos/5c1ae77ae91b067f6d57dec0/master/pass/Comparison-City-MAIN-ART.jpg" alt="">
        </div>
        <div class="col-md-3 col-12">
          <img width="100%" src="https://media.wired.com/photos/5c1ae77ae91b067f6d57dec0/master/pass/Comparison-City-MAIN-ART.jpg" alt="">
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  
  <script
  src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.4.1.min.js"
  integrity="sha256-CSXorXvZcTkaix6Yvo6HppcZGetbYMGWSFlBw8HfCJo="
  crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
  <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.12.9/umd/popper.min.js" integrity="sha384-ApNbgh9B+Y1QKtv3Rn7W3mgPxhU9K/ScQsAP7hUibX39j7fakFPskvXusvfa0b4Q" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
  <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-JZR6Spejh4U02d8jOt6vLEHfe/JQGiRRSQQxSfFWpi1MquVdAyjUar5+76PVCmYl" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

Hope it'll help